# Java Error: Input cannot be resolved

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I am new to Java. Please bear with me. I am trying a simple program. The number of dogs equal a certain amount of points. 4 or more dogs equal 60 points.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Welcome {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int dogs,points; 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of dogs: ");
    int dogs = input.nextInt();

    switch (dogs)
    {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("You've earned 0 points!");
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You've earned 5 points!");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("You've earned 15 points!");
        break;

    default: System.out.println("You've earned 60 points!");


        }
```

}
}
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sure, what problems are you facing?

Comment: Results do not output, only the error: input cannot be resolved is shown.

Comment: that's because you've called your scanner `scan` and not `input` so change this `input.nextInt();` to this `scan.nextInt();` and change this `int dogs = input.nextInt();` to this `dogs = scan.nextInt();` as `dogs` is already defined.

Comment: According to your code, you have to use scan.nextInt()

Comment: That did the trick. Also, a simple question is: Why does case 0's output also results in "You've earned 5 points" as well as "you've earned 0 points" I would only like the 0 points to display.

Comment: @user7729282 insert the `break` after the `println` for the `case 0:`, otherwise you'll get a _fallthrough_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Welcome {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dogs;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of dogs: ");
    dogs = scan.nextInt();

    switch (dogs) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("You've earned 0 points!");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You've earned 5 points!");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You've earned 15 points!");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You've earned 30 points!");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You've earned 60 points!");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("You've earned 60 points!");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: suppose `int dogs = scan.nextInt();` is the only change needed.

Comment: This does the trick, except for case 0 it outputs two results: "You've earned 0 points and you've earned 5 points".

Comment: @RajithPemabandu You forgot a break statement after case 0